# How do I efficiently use the Stack Exchange Questions API when multiple redundant tags of interest exist?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I work at Pebble and we're trying to push our developers towards resources like Stack Overflow to help them get their technical questions answered. At the moment, we are using the Stack Exchange API to pull the 10 most recent questions and 10 highest rated questions via the [Questions API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions). This API does not support more than one tag as a parameter.

However, on Stack Overflow, there are three essentially similar/redundant tags used: [pebble-watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pebble-watch), [pebble-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pebble-sdk) and [cloudpebble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudpebble). There are many cases where developers have tagged their questions with 1, 2 or 3 of these tags because they don't know which one to use (CloudPebble questions are sometimes distinguishably different enough to be tagged as [cloudpebble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudpebble)). We want to make sure all relevant questions are returned in the API call, but currently, doing so requires 6 separate API calls (besides being confusing when it comes time to create and tag a question).

My colleagues tried to edit some old questions to get the [pebble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pebble) consolidation started on Stack Overflow (we'd like to replace the [pebble-watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pebble-watch), [pebble-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pebble-sdk) and [cloudpebble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudpebble)). However, in all cases, @Charles, who self-identifies himself as "a proud member of the New Tag Deletionist Cabal" reverted the changes.

We'd really like to make this easier for Pebble developers. What is the recommended way to reduce confusion from these extra tags and make it possible to retrieve all of the relevant questions without running out of API calls? How will the limitations by the Stack Exchange API and Stack Exchange/Overflow moderation policies be reconciled? Is there someplace where we can start an open discussion?

Comment: "New Tag Deletionist Cabal" - someone they've never seen on the site before starts making tag changes on their own without first asking anyone about it, of course they're going to form a cabal, drink wine and walk around in slankets

Comment: @AlE. I posted on Meta Stack Exchange because this seems to be a general moderation policy across all sites (and this request originated because we are using the Stack Exchange API to pull questions, which doesn't support querying for multiple tags at once)

Comment: @random My more reputable colleagues made the changes on Stack Overflow, as the site (correctly) restricts what I am able to do. Is there a place to ask on Stack Overflow/Exchange? That would certainly be better than the "Ask for forgiveness later" approach.

Comment: @DeerHunter, I'm not name-calling, the moderator [Charles](http://stackoverflow.com/users/168868/charles) self-identifies himself as "a proud member of the New Tag Deletionist Cabal"

Comment: @girlgrammer, you may be able to use the fact that the the favorite tags functionality can use wildcard syntax like "pebble*" or "*pebble*".

Comment: @girlgrammer that user is not a moderator.

Comment: @LanceRoberts are you referring to the [questions/unanswered/my-tags](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/unanswered-questions-my-tags) API call? We'd ideally like to grab both answered and unanswered questions. (Thanks for the help/response!)

Comment: I understand the first bit of your question, but the last bit and final question I don't understand. What *exactly* do you want? `What is the recommended way to reduce confusion from these extra tags and make it possible to retrieve all of the relevant questions without running out of API calls? How will the limitations by the Stack Exchange API and Stack Exchange/Overflow moderation policies be reconciled? Is there someplace where we can start an open discussion?` seems to be asking 3 separate issues. However, this question mainly seems to be about the SE API, so I think we can reopen it.

Comment: @girlgrammer, I haven't played with the API calls.  I'm just noting that since the Favorite Tag mechanism can filter based on wildcards, that it might be implemented in other components of SE like some of the APIs.  You'd probably just have to experiment and see what wildcarding does for you.

Comment: Oh btw, I tried looking at your website, the domain name expired a couple of days ago :)

Comment: @girlgrammer, ok, see the last sentence I edited into my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, [you *can* pull the information you need from the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search#order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=pebble-watch%3Bpebble-sdk%3Bcloudpebble&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) - don't neglect StackApps with your API questions; [there's a lot of good information there](https://stackapps.com/questions/4120/possible-to-get-more-than-5-tags-for-search-or-to-use-or-logic-for-tags-in)!

That said, unifying these tags still sounds like a good idea. I don't see any particular reason for [pebble-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pebble-sdk) and [pebble-watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pebble-watch) to be different things; what about merging them both into [pebble-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pebble-sdk)?  [cloud-pebble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-pebble)*sounds* like it should be something different, but the questions are *mostly* just overlapping with [pebble-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pebble-sdk) - we should probably either merge it into that tag as well, or at least remove it from all the questions that aren't directly concerned with the service.

This'll leave you with either two tags to monitor (one with rather low traffic) or just one.

Answer (score 10):

It's not the API, but tag searches (as well as favorite tags) support wildcards. So, for example, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*pebble*` will take you to a page that lists all questions with "pebble" somewhere in the tags.

For the use cases you mentioned, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*pebble*?sort=newest&pageSize=10` and `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*pebble*?sort=votes&pageSize=10` will pull the 10 newest and 10 highest voted questions, respectively.

Comment: The API also supports searches, with multiple tags: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search#order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=pebble-watch%3Bpebble-sdk%3Bcloudpebble&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true

Answer (score 4):

Both the Favorite Tags interface and the Search Box allow the use of wildcards.
So for example you can search for

> [*pebble*]

and it will transmogrify it to

> [pebble-watch] or [pebble-sdk] or [cloudpebble]

It doesn't appear that the *tagged* parameter for the API supports wildcards though.

In your case though, since there are only three tags to worry about you can use the *tagged* parameter with all three delimited by semicolons using the /search API.

> /2.2/search?order=desc&sort=creation&**tagged=pebble-watch;pebble-sdk;cloudpebble**&site=stackoverflow

Comment: `;` between tags works as AND