# How can I use the API to access private team information?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, api

I am trying to query information from my private team and tried the following:

1. Registered an app

   ```
   Name = stackoverflow.com/c/{team}
   OAuth domain = stackoverflow.com
   Application web site = https://stackoverflow.com/c/{team}
   ```

Got client id, client secret and a key.

2. Authentication trial (explicit)

I have put into the browser the following URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/?client_id={id}&scope=no_expiry&redirect_uri=https://stackoverflow.com
```

Got the code.

Switched to Postman and got the `access_token` based on `client_id`, `client_secret`, `redirect_uri` and the code.

Now, I am trying to use a simple API method to check if I can access anything for my Team:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site={???}&access_token={token}&key={key}
```

This works for Stack Overflow. Tried with `stackoverflow/c/{team}`, but it does not know about it (which kind of makes sense since I expected to generate some sort of key inside my private team space).

3. I have replaced the first step's URL with:

   ```
   https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/?client_id={client_id}&scope=access_team|https://stackoverflow/c/{team}&redirect_uri=https://stackoverflow.com
   ```

Got a rather long code and switched to Postman:

```
GET: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=stackoverflow&team=https://stackoverflow.com/c/{team}&key={key}
Headers: X-API-Access-Token = {the_code_from_previous_step}
```

If I do not specify the key, I receive the following error:

> { 
>         "error_id": 405, 
>      "error_message": "key is
>   required when access_token is passed.", 
>         "error_name":
>   "key_required" 
>   }

If I specify the key I got when defining the app:

> { 
>  "error_id": 403, 
>  "error_message": "key is not valid for
>   passed access_token, token not found.", 
>  "error_name":
>   "access_denied" 
>  }

What is the correct way to retrieve information from my team?

Comment: Do you think that Meta Stack Overflow is the best place to ask this about the SE API?

Comment: @double-beep - this is more about the stack-overflow-for-teams than the API itself (they have the tag here). Also, [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260272/how-do-i-efficiently-use-the-stack-exchange-questions-api-when-multiple-redundan) deals with SE API and was migrated here, so I guess this is an appropriate place. Do you think I could increase my chances of getting an answer elsewhere?

Comment: You might not need `https://` protocol prefix on the `teams` query parameter, e.g. `?team=stackoverflow.com/c/pickles`.

Comment: Just FYI there is https://stackapps.com where you can ask about the SE API. The question you mentioned was migrated from meta Stack Exchange, but not from StackApps. I think it is worth trying it. Delete this question, repost it in StackApps and hope for help. However, note that now you got help, so it is no longer worth trying it :)

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackapps.com/questions/8202/unable-to-make-api-calls-using-access-token-for-private-stack-overflow-teams-sit

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like the `scope` query parameter you passed when obtaining your access token didn't have the `access_team|stackoverflow.com/c/your-team-url`, as detailed [in the Teams-specific docs](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams).

I think you'd want `scope=no_expiry,access_team|stackoverflow.com/c/your-team-url`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have just realized that and I am trying to check all the flow.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your initial error and changing the scope does allow you into the API; however, I got a `"this method is not supported when querying a team"` response on the `/info` route.  Changing to `/posts` showed me all is working!

Comment: Now everything is clear. However, I think the documentation should have been more straightforward for SO for Teams (i.e. one page including the flows for it, not having to look for multiple times in two places). Thanks for the support.